# What does moduleDirectory mean in the eslint file?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I cannot find a documentation of eslint that explains the setting property and its child properties. What does "moduleDirectory" and "some_folder" mean in the example below?

.eslintrc.json

```
 {"settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
          "node": {
            "paths": ["src"],
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
            "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/", "some_folder"]
          }
        }
      },
    rules { ... }
    ...}
```